# short term for incrementing in java

Tags: java

I am quite confused if there any difference the two below.  I think they are doing the same thing but when I compile it seems like they are different.  Thank you in advance.

```
if(hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)]>=0) {
    hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)]++;    
    // do other things        
}

if(hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)]++>=0) {
    // do other things        
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't increment if `hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)]` is less than 0.

Comment: To put @shmosel's comment another way, the second one will always increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactoring to remove the postfix operators, the first one is equivalent to this:

```
if(hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)] >= 0) {
    hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)] += 1;    
    // do other things
}
```

The second (assuming your `hash` members are integers) is equivalent to this:

```
int tmp = hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)];
hash[s.charAt(leftIdx)] += 1;
if(tmp >= 0) {
    // do other things
}
```

The postfix `++` operator returns the pre-incremented value and then increments it as a side-effect. So your `if` in the 2nd example is using the pre-incremented value in its condition (represented by `tmp` above).